# Table doesn't have a primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

i get the following exception  (missing primary key) in the line of using Find() method

> "Table doesn't have a primary key."

I've rechecked the Database and all Primary Key columns are set correctly.

my code:

```
DataTable dt = p.GetAllPhotos(int.Parse(Id));
DataTable temp = new DataTable();
temp = dt.Clone();
temp = (DataTable)(Session["currentImage"]);
DataTable dtvalid = new DataTable();
dtvalid = dt.Clone();
DataRow[] drr = new DataRow[1];
drr[0] = dt.Rows.Find((int.Parse(temp.Rows[0]["photoId"].ToString()))+1);
foreach (DataRow dr in drr)
{
    dtvalid.ImportRow(dr);
}
dtvalid.AcceptChanges();'
```

Comment: What the heck are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to set the **PrimaryKey** property of your **DataTable** object before you call **Find**

```
DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
keyColumns[0] = dt.Columns["<columnname>"];
dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
```

Comment: thank u so much , this is the solution.
i think this is similar to when we should identify the data key name property for some controls in ASP.net

Comment: Be careful that you copy the columnname correctly.  I had DemoKey_pk in the code, but the stored procedure was returning DemoKey_fk.  Since DemoKey_pk was not being returned (DemoKey_fk was/is) my code threw up with the "Table doesn't have a primary key" exception.