# Update command on a table without a primary key

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a table without a primary key,

I'm trying to use a `SqlDataAdapter` to update the table:

```
public void Update(DataTable dataTable)
{
     SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
     string query = $"select * from {dataTable.TableName}";
     sqlDa.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, _internalConnection);
     SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDa);
     sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
     sqlDa.Update(dataTable);
     sqlDa.Dispose();
}
```

Clearly this won't work, because this requires a primary key. But what if I don't have a primary key? I can populate my DataGridView just fine, but when it comes to updating - how exactly can I do this?

Comment: Write your own SqlCommand and assign it to the UpdateCommand manually

Comment: @Steve, this is coming from a grid, so how would I know what to update. I would assume the dataTable has some ordinal rownumber sync with the db to pull this off?

Comment: But do you have any unique field present in your query? If you don't have a primarykey you could still create an update command if there is some field in your table that uniquely identifies the record.

Comment: Why don't you have a primary key? In order to work with the data, you need a way to uniquely identify each row, which is what a primary key provides.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567552/table-doesnt-have-a-primary-key

Comment: At least *set of all feileds* is your primary key. Isn't it? If yes, then you can write INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE command yourself in a way which can be used by `SqlDataAdapter`.