# "Table does not contain primary key"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to populate a combo box based off of the value member that has been selected from a data grid view.

Here is my code to initialise it

```
            DataSet dsCIF2 = new DataSet();
            DataRow drPitch;
            String sqlPitch = @" Select * from Pitch";
            String connStr5 = Properties.Resources.cString;
            SqlDataAdapter daPitch = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlPitch, connStr5);
            DataTable dtPitch = new DataTable();
            daPitch.Fill(dtPitch);
            daPitch.Fill(dsCIF2, "Pitch");

            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "PitchDesc";
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "PitchID";
            comboBox2.DataSource = dtPitch;
```

With the following code I use this to find the ID of the pitch from the selected row on the data grid view and it returns the correct pitch ID, as seen through debugging.

```
 int matchBookingID = 0;
            matchBookingID = Convert.ToInt32(DGV.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            drMatchData = dsCIF.Tables["MatchStats"].Rows.Find(matchBookingID);
                Pitch = Convert.ToInt32(drMatchData["PitchID"].ToString());
```

Now when I try to use that ID to find the datarow within the pitch table I get an error saying

**Table doesn't have a primary key**

on this line of code

```
                drPitch = dsCIF2.Tables["Pitch"].Rows.Find(Pitch);
```

I don't know why I am getting this error, thanks in advance!

*Update: The table does have a primary key*
SQL CODE

```
create TABLE PITCH
(
PitchID int NOT NULL,
PitchDesc varchar(30) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT pkPitchID PRIMARY KEY(PitchID),
)
```

Comment: My instinctive answer to this is that you have not set the ID field as the primary key in your SQL database.  EF doesn't play nicely with tables that do not have primary keys.

Comment: UPDATE: yes the table does a have primary key, I have even dropped it and created it again with new values

Comment: Can you export the table creation script as a SQL query and add it to the question please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table doesn't have a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567552/table-doesnt-have-a-primary-key)

Comment: @DylanBrams I have tried that and it makes no difference.  Thanks anyway for the suggestion

Comment: @DylanBrams Also I didn't have to do it for the MatchBookings table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to fill the schema of the table.  It works now that I have added the following line of code to the initialisation code

```
daPitch.FillSchema(dsCIF2, SchemaType.Source, "Pitch");
```

It now looks like this

```
DataSet dsCIF2 = new DataSet();

String sqlPitch = @" Select * from Pitch";
String connStr5 = Properties.Resources.cString;
SqlDataAdapter daPitch = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlPitch, connStr5);
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBPitch = new SqlCommandBuilder(daPitch);

daPitch.FillSchema(dsCIF2, SchemaType.Source, "Pitch");

DataTable dtPitch = new DataTable();
daPitch.Fill(dtPitch);
daPitch.Fill(dsCIF2, "Pitch");
```