# Table doesn't have a primary key idpdf

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Why am I getting this error

> table doesn't have a primary key.

Although I made (idpdf) primary during create my table (pdfinfo)

in this line

```
Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows.Find(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
```

[image]

```
 Private Sub mylib_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    adapter = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from pdfinfo ", connection)
    adapter.Fill(dt)

    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "pdfname"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "idpdf"

    dt.Constraints.Add("Primary", dt.Columns("idpdf"), True)


End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim filename As String = ComboBox1.Text
    Dim row As DataRow = dt.Rows.Find(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
    Dim file_data() As Byte = CType(row(2), Byte())
    Dim fs As New FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)

    fs.Write(file_data, 0, file_data.Length)
    fs.Close()

    Process.Start(filename)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to set the primary key constraint before you assign `dt` to the combo box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table doesn't have a primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3567552/table-doesnt-have-a-primary-key)

Comment: Assuming that your database table has a primary key, set the `MissingSchemaAction` of your data adapter to `AddWithKey`.  Calling `Fill` will then automatically set the `PrimaryKey` of your `DataTable`.

Comment: That said, what's the point of calling `Find` in that context anyway?  Just use `DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row` to get that `DataRow`.  In fact, you don't even need the `DataRow` because the `DataRowView` you get from the `SelectedItem` can give you the field data anyway.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you this " DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row " solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

To define the primary key for a table you should use the [PrimaryKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.primarykey?view=netframework-4.7.2) property not the [Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/datatable-constraints) which is used for Foreign Keys or Unique constraints.

```
dt.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dt.Columns("idpdf"))
```